# Finding the missing digits

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I was solving a URI question about finding the minor number that's multiple of a divisor given.
I found this problem:

Dividend: 4?3?771?2?166??56??357?2223

Divisor: 909

I need to fill my dividend '?' with numbers, and find the lowest possibly number that result in a remainder = 0, without modifying the fixed numbers.

I tried some brute force with Python but i didn't get a fast algorithm.

How can i do that?

Comment: I thought it was $9^{10}$. Anyway, a number divisible $909$ must be divisible by both $9$ and $101$. A number divisible by $9$ must have its sum of digits divisible by $9$. A number divisible by $101$, the alternating sum of blocks of two from right to left is divisible by $101$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Notable_examples) for more shortcuts of this kind.

Comment: Possibly helpful: we can write all candidates in the form
$$
N + \sum_{i=1}^9 a_{i} 10^{k_i},
$$
where $N = 403077102016600560035702223$ and each $a_1,\dots,a_9$ is a digit from $0$ to $9$ and the exponents $k_1,\dots,k_9$ are $4,8,9,12,13,17,19,23,25$.

Our goal is to find $a_i$ for which the resulting sum is equal to $0$ modulo $101$ and modulo $9$.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was an interesting programming exercise, so I put something together. Here is what I ended up with:

```
import math
import time

    
def fill_in(N,exps): #returns True,list if successful
    n = 909
    if exps:
        ten_pow = 10**exps[0]
        for a in range(10):
            flag,coefs = fill_in(N + a*ten_pow,exps[1:])
            if flag:
                coefs.insert(0,a)
                return (True,coefs)
        return (False,[])
    else:
        return ((N%n == 0),[])

start_time = time.time()
N = 403077102016600560035702223
exps = [25,23,19,17,13,12,9,8,4]
flag,ans = fill_in(N,exps)
print("Answer:")
print(ans)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

My output:

```
Answer:
[0, 0, 4, 6, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9]
--- 2.5748291015625 seconds ---
```

Apparently, the answer is
$$
4\color{red}{0}3\color{red}{0}771\color{red}{4}2
\color{red}{6}166\color{red}{9}\color{red}{8}56
\color{red}{9}\color{red}{9}357\color{red}{9}2223.
$$
With W|A, we see that this number is [indeed divisible by 909](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=403077142616698569935792223%20mod%20909).

---

To make this all a bit more adaptable:

```
def fill_in_str(string):
    exps = [i for i in range(len(string)) if string[-i-1] == '?'][::-1]
    N_str = string.replace('?','0')
    flag,ans = fill_in(int(N),exps)
    if flag:
        return string.replace('?','%d') % tuple(ans)
    else:
        return 'NONE'

string = '4?3?771?2?166??56??357?2223'
output = fill_in_str(string)
print("Answer: " + output)
```

Output:

```
Answer: 403077142616698569935792223
```

---

**Explanation:** The function `fill_in(N,exps,n)` takes a number $N$, a list of exponents $k_1,\dots,k_q$ in descending order, and $n$ (in this case $n = 909$). It looks for numbers $a_1,\dots,a_q$ such that $N + \sum_{i=1}^q a_i 10^{k_i}$ is divisible by $909$. If it finds such numbers, then it returns a flag "True" and the list of coefficients $[a_1,\dots,a_q]$. Otherwise, it returns "False" and an empty list.

The function works recursively: it takes every value for $a_1$ from $a_1 = 0,\dots,9$ and then looks for coefficients $a_2,\dots,a_q$ such that
$$
N + a_1 10^{k_1} + \sum_{i=2}^q a_i 10^{k_i}
$$
is divisible by $n$.

The bottom of the recurrence occurs for the empty list of exponents: if there are no coefficients left to fill in, then it's simply a matter of whether the number we ended up with (by filling in all the $a_i$) is a multiple of $n$.

*Note: For what it's worth, I did try testing mod $9$ and mod $101$ separately to "make things faster". It does not save any time.*

---

An interesting alternative that's slower, but shorter and easier to understand:

```
def fill_in_v2(string):
    n = 909
    fstr = string.replace('?','%s')
    num_uk = string.count('?')
    for i in range(10**(num_uk+1)):
        istr = str(i).zfill(num_uk)
        nstr = fstr % tuple(istr)
        if int(nstr)%n == 0:
            return nstr
    return 'NONE'

start_time = time.time()
string = '4?3?771?2?166??56??357?2223'
output = fill_in_v2(string)
print("Answer: " + output)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
Answer: 403077142616698569935792223
--- 6.86776328086853 seconds ---
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you briefly describe what algorithm this is?

Comment: @an4s I added a bit of an explanation. Is everything clear now?

Comment: @an4s I changed my answer a bit. The "time-saving" modular exponentiation method was only slowing things down, so now it's twice as fast.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense! Thanks for the explanation. Since each missing digit is initialized to $0$, the algorithm _should_ find the smallest number larger than $403077102016600560035702223$ that is divisible by $909$, correct?

Comment: @an4s Yes, that's correct. Another important piece here is that the digits are incremented from least significant to most significant (which is why it is important that the list is decreasing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BenGrossmann! Helped a lot! :D

Answer (score 2):

Render the unknown digits $a$ to $i$ from left to right.  Let's try to use divisibility tests:

1. Divisibility by $101$: Alternating sum of two-digit blocks from the right is multiple of $101$.

$-4+10a+3-10b-7+71-10c-2+10d+1-66+10e+f-56+10g+h-35+70+i-22+23\to 10(a-b-c+d+e+g)+(f+h+i)=101m+24$

Note that with nonnegative single digits for each of the unknowns, the left side can't be greater than $387$ or less than $-180$.  This forces $m\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$. We file that away for later use.

2. Divisibility by $9$:  Sum of **the same pairs of digits as above** is divisible by $9$.  This looks strange, but soon we will see why we are doing this.

$4+10a+3+10b+7+71+10c+2+10d+1+66+10e+f+56+10g+h+35+70+i+22+23\to 10(a+b+c+d+e+g)+(f+h+i)=9n$ (the known digits cancel $\bmod 9$).

Here $n$ is a nonnegative whole number less than or equal to $63$.

Now let us subtract the first equation from the second, causing most terms on the left to cancel:

$20(b+c)=9n-101m-24$

Now, the right side must be a nonnegative multiple of $20$, less than or equal to $18×20=360$, with $m$ having one of the values identified earlier.  We try them out, identifying all solutions for each $m$ that satisfy $0\le b+c\le 18$ and $0\le n\le63$:

$m=-2\to 20(b+c)=9n+178; n=18; b+c=17$

$m=-1\to 20(b+c)=9n+77; n\in\{7,27\}; b+c\in\{7,16\}$

$m=0\to 20(b+c)=9n-24; n\in\{16,36\}; b+c\in\{6,15\}$

$m=1\to 20(b+c)=9n-125; n\in\{25,45\}; b+c\in\{5,14\}$

$m=2\to 20(b+c)=9n-226; n\in\{34,54\}; b+c\in\{4,13\}$

$m=3\to 20(b+c)=9n-327; n\in\{43,63\}; b+c\in\{3,12\}$

We are seeking the minimal solution, so we take $b+c=3$ with $b=0,c=3$, right?  We carry this through.  With $b+c=3$ we have $m=3,n=43$ and thus the sum $10(a+b+c+d+e+g)+(f+h+i)$ obtained from our test for divisibility by $9$ will be $387$.  Then $f+h+i$ must end in $7$ and to minimize the higher-valued digits we should render this sum as large as possible.  Therefore $f,h,i$ are all $9$.  This together with $b=0,c=3$ leaves $(387-30-27)/10=33$ for the sum of the remaining four digits, and to minimize the total number we select $a=6,d=e=g=9$.

The resulting number is divisible by $909$, but it has a relatively high digit $a$ whose place value exceeds that of $b$ or $c$.  So maybe a higher value of $b+c$ could give a lower value of $a$.  Can we get $a$ down to $0$, and what is the smallest increment in $b+c$, and therefore $c$ with $b=0$, we need to do so?

For $b+c=4,b=0,c=4$ we have $m=2,n=34$.  The sum in our $9$-divisibility test is now $306$, ending in $6$.  Therefore $f+h+i$ must follow suit.  We again maximize this sum and, finding two distinct values, we select the smaller one for $f$.  Thus $f=8,h=i=9$.  The remaining digits $a,d,e,g$ will now sum to $(306-40-26)/10=24$.  Since **this is less than or equal to $27$**, we can set $a=0$ and apportion the sum of $24$ among $d,e,g$.  So the minimal solution, with the smallest possible value for $a$ and not unnecessarily large values for $b,c$ or $d$, is rendered by

$a=b=0, c=4, d=6, e=9, f=8, g=h=i=9.$

$N=403077142616698569935792223.$

Modulo $909$, the place values (powers of $10$) follow the cycle $\overline{1,10,100,91}$.  There are no unknowns with the place values $\equiv100$, but for the other three residues we see separate ascending sequences for the unknown digits:

$\equiv1:  f\le h\le i$

$\equiv10:  a\le d\le e\le g$

$\equiv91:  b\le c$

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the '?' spots with $0$'s leads us to define $N$ and calculate

$\quad N = 403077102016600560035702223 \equiv 279 \pmod{909}$

Note: the OP's starting number had all non-zero digits with the question marks, so all the zeroes in $N$ are open to substitution.

We also have for $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$,

$\quad k * 10^0 \equiv k\pmod{909}$
$\quad k * 10^1 \equiv k * 10^1 \pmod{909}$
$\quad k * 10^2 \equiv k * 10^2 \pmod{909}$
$\quad k * 10^3 \equiv k * 91 \pmod{909}$
$\quad k * 10^4 \equiv k \pmod{909}$

Now since $279 + 630 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$, we can 'work off' the $630$ deficit by writing

$\quad N + 6 * 10^3 + 8 *10 + 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$

Employing cyclic shift logic to find a '? \ $0$' spot,

$\quad N + 6 * 10^3 + 8 *10 + 4 =$
$\quad \quad 403077102016600560035702223 + 6 * 10^3 + 8 *10 + 4 \equiv$
$\quad \quad 4030771\color{red}{6}2016600560035702223 + 8 *10 + 4 \equiv$
$\quad \quad 4030771\color{red}{6}201660056\color{red}{8}035702223 + 4 \equiv$
$\quad \quad 4030771\color{red}{6}201660056\color{red}{8}0357\color{red}{4}2223 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$

So we've found a solution and now we want to minimize it. It turns out that the decimal expansion spots at

$\quad 10^2, 10^6, 10^{10}, 10^{14}, 10^{18}, 10^{22},  10^{26}$

for the number $N$ are not the '? \ $0$' spots; this is a simplifying constraint for the OP's problem.

Exercise: Find the minimum solution for $\;\,4?3?771?2?166??56??357?2223 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$.
Hint: Show that there are no solutions for $4\color{red}{0}3\color{red}{0}771\color{red}{3}2?166??56??357?2223 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$ with some accompanying solution logic.

Comment: "Show that there are no solutions for $4\color{red}{0}3\color{red}{0}771\color{red}{3}2?166??56??357?2223 \equiv 0 \pmod{909}$ with some accompanying solution logic."  Because this would force three other unknown digits to sum to more than 3×9.  See my answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Certainly more than one way to skin a cat here,

Comment: @OscarLanzi But all solutions most likely have to examine inequalities.